# Proof of measurable function

Tags: probability

If X is no. Of times the coin is tossed until head appears how do we show that X: S -> R is F-B(R) measurable?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.  What do all these letters mean?

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that $X^{-1}(-\infty,x]\in F$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e., $\{\omega:X(\omega)\leq x\}\in F$. I suppose that $S=\{(H), \ (TH), \ (TTH), \ (TTTH),\dots\},$ where $H$ stands for heads and $T$ for tails. Note that $X$ takes countably infinite number of values. Hence, we can write $X^{-1}(-\infty,x]$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ as follows:
$$
X^{-1}(-\infty,x] = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \emptyset & \quad x < 1 \\
             \{(H)\}& \quad 1\le x  <2\\
\{(TH)\}& \quad 2\le x  <3 \\
\{(TTH)\}& \quad 3\le x  <4 \\
\ \ \vdots
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
Therefore, $X^{-1}(-\infty,x]\in F$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and the claim follows.